# Как получить картинку контакта в Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Я написал небольшой код, который возвращает URI контакта, выбранного в "Контакты", потом я пытаюсь получить всю инфу по этому контакту, в т.ч. и его картинку, я делаю поиск по Cursor на наличие фото методом `cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO)`, но это не даёт результата, хотя картинка есть в контактах.

Comment: На данный момент получилось только получить URI картинки в базе данных, т.е. она там точно есть, но раздекодить картинку по URI тоже не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение проблемы.

Нужно было получить Id контакта, потом по этому ID получить Uri картинки, для этого необходимо выполнить:

```
Cursor cursor_contact_info = getContentResolver().query(Здесь вписываем URI нужного контакта, new String[]{ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI}, null, null, null);
```

`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI` Хранит в себе Uri для оригинальной картинки, а `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI` для сжатой, далее необходимо загрузить по этому URI саму картинку, но не методом **BitmapFactory.decodeStream()**, а методом **MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Здесь нужно вставить URI, которое мы получили в *CURSOR*);**

Answer (score 2):

Поле `ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO` содержит блоб иконки контакта, блоб надо читать потоком `InputStream`. Чтобы получить из него битмап надо подавать на вход `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`

См. [документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) примерно так:

```
public static Bitmap getContactPhoto(Context context, long  contactId) {
   ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
   Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
   InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
   return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал данный метод, но он не вывел картинку у нужного контакта, но вывел картинку у другого, причём непонятно какую и откуда он её взял

Comment: Да ладно :) Скорее всего, вы путаете `contactId` - метод работает железобетонно - я из своего кода ее выдрал

Comment: Я вам верю, может, и моя ошибка, но я брал все контакты из телефонной книги и их ID, результат получился корявым, т.к. к нужному контакту картинка не подкрепилась, но картинка подкрепилась к тому контакту, который вообще был без картинка ему была присвоена, которая вообще в контактах не находится, да и на телефоне я её вообще не сохранял. 

Документацию я посмотрел, спасибо большое, там всё чётко, буду действовать, как там написано, жаль, сам данный метод не нашёл, т.к. искал в http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.html

Comment: Я уже не знаю, что делать, я перепробовал и ваш метод, и всякий, но не получается. Я точно уверен, что id контакта передаётся правильно, также я проверил, что URI маленькой картинки и большой также передаётся, т.е. они действительно есть, но вот достать она их не хочет, я уже перепробовал массу способов с InputStream, но не получается. Я пытался вашим методом, также тем, который описан в вашей ссылке на документацию, также пытался просто загрузить обычным потоком "InputStream input = new URL("Здесь URI картинки").openStream();" с последующей декодировкой в BitmapFactory.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK покажите, откуда вы берете id контакта?

Comment: Я написал коротенький код для получения id контакта, при выборе его из списка контактов, Data хранит в себе Uri контакта, а методом getLastPathSegment() я получаю сам Id, далее с ним работаю. Я написал ещё отдельную прогу, которая выводит все контакты с их именами и ID в список, я сравнивал ID, они верные.